# How to fix AsyncStorage has been removed from react-native core

Tags: dom, document-ready

i tried to authenticate my sign up with firebase so on the sign up screen  the error only appear when i  import { auth } from '../firebase'; if  i comment it the code work fine but if try to use it in my sign up.js screen i got the error above and in the picture if i import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'; the code work fine but without erro but cant authenticate but if i add  import { auth } from '../firebase';  i got the error in the image

i have got stack so please unstack me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unistalling `node-module, package-lock(if you are using npm)or yarn(if you are using yarn)`. Remove all the firebase relate packages in package.json. Then run `npm install or yarn install`
Install firebase using expo official documentation
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/

Then run `expo r -c`

Comment: the answer help i hope it might help u too